# Cobbler import of RHEL6 DVD doesn't seem to create yum repo

Tags: redhat, yum, repository, cobbler

I setup cobbler (2.4.0) and imported the RHEL6.4 DVD.  It copies all of the packages over to /var/www/cobbler/ks_mirror/RHEL6.4-x86_64.  It even runs `createrepo` and loads the metadata, etc.

So you would think that with 'yum_post_install_mirror: 1' set in /etc/cobbler/settings, a new kickstart would point to this yum repo automatically to add add'l packages.  It doesn't.  Cobbler does create a blank repo file in the new host though.

If you run `cobbler repo list` it becomes apparent that cobbler did not in fact setup a public repo at all because it is empty.

Is this intended behavior?  What would be the right way to make the repo available to new kickstarts without just creating another copy of the data?  Also this cobbler install is airgapped for security reasons, so I can't just reposync to RHN.